# Jwplayer video not working in chrome

Tags: javascript, facebook, google-chrome, video, jwplayer

We are sharing jwplayer videos on facebook. The vidoes played fine on all other browser except chrome.

Please share below link on facebook on chrome and play the video, you will see player is disorderd and video is not played.

http://isp-dev.deliveredoncloud.com/facebook-video?v_key=atHlbXDD

The link is verified on facebook and OG debugger, it return response:206.

Any help, **why video is not played in chrome.**
[player condition in chrom when played](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TejjE.png)

Comment: It might be a good idea to add some screenshots of the issue/errors - I doubt people are going to be willing to share a random video on their Facebook.

Comment: Chrome console says, _“Refused to connect to `https://jwpsrv.a.ssl.fastly.net/content/conversions/M2UErINw/videos/atHlbXDD-23541866.mp4?token=[…]` because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "connect-src *.facebook.com *.fbcdn.net *.facebook.net *.spotilocal.com:* *.akamaihd.net wss://*.facebook.com:* https://fb.scanandcleanlocal.com:* *.atlassolutions.com attachment.fbsbx.com ws://localhost:* blob: 127.0.0.1:* http://*.serialpodcast.org https://*.serialpodcast.org".”_ – so this is likely something the JW people will have to fix on their end.

Comment: do you have a link for this ? , @CBroe : where did you get this error?

Comment: @hitesh: As I said, in Chrome’s console. (Version 48.0.2564.116 m on Win 7)

Comment: Were you able to fix this? I'm not seeing any issues with playback or getting an error, even on Version 48 on Win 7

Comment: Guys problem solved by using swf file and player, but i am my actual requirement is to paly MP4. MP4 file is played in all browser except crome. So for the time being i fix it with flash player. @CBroe really i didn't seen any error in console.

Answer (score 0):

From the error in your comments it looks like Chrome is enforcing content security policies.

These are described quite well here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/CSP/CSP_policy_directives and here: http://content-security-policy.com

Note in particular the browser support table in the first link (this will hopefully be updated regularly so is not a good thing to show here as it would just be a current snapshot).

You can experiment wit different settings, maybe trying a very open policy initially to make sure this is not masking some other issue.